# error C2664: cannot convert argument 2 from 'const ATL::CAdapt<ATL::CComPtr<IZipFileEntry>> *' to 'ATL::CAdapt<ATL::CComPtr<IZipFileEntry>> *'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, visual-studio-2013, atl

I'm migrating VS2008(VC++) code to VS2013. I get the below error:

```
error C2664: 'HRESULT _CopyItfFromAdaptItf<IZipFileEntry>::copy(T **,ATL::CAdapt<ATL::CComPtr<T>> *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'const ATL::CAdapt<ATL::CComPtr<IZipFileEntry>> *' to 'ATL::CAdapt<ATL::CComPtr<IZipFileEntry>> *'
```

The error appears in the Visual studio SDK File, how is it possible?. I'm not able to fix this error. Please find below the output and error line below.

Thanks a lot for any help!!

**Output:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(5818): error C2664: 'HRESULT _CopyItfFromAdaptItf<IZipFileEntry>::copy(T **,ATL::CAdapt<ATL::CComPtr<T>> *)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'const ATL::CAdapt<ATL::CComPtr<IZipFileEntry>> *' to 'ATL::CAdapt<ATL::CComPtr<IZipFileEntry>> *'
      with
      [
          T=IZipFileEntry
      ]
      Conversion loses qualifiers
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(5803) : while compiling class template member function 'HRESULT ATL::ICollectionOnSTLImpl<IZipFileDir1,EntryList,IZipFileEntry *,_CopyItfFromAdaptItf<IZipFileEntry>,EntryEnum>::get_Item(long,ItemType *)'
      with
      [
          ItemType=IZipFileEntry *
      ]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(5140) : see reference to class template instantiation 'ATL::ICollectionOnSTLImpl<IZipFileDir1,EntryList,IZipFileEntry *,_CopyItfFromAdaptItf<IZipFileEntry>,EntryEnum>' being compiled
```

**Error Code:**

```
if (iter != m_coll.end())
      hr = CopyItem::copy(pvar, &*iter); // Error C2664
return hr;
```

P.S: I'm not able to edit and save this atlcom.h file. I get access to the path is denied error message. Is this because its a SDK File?

Some more code definitions added:

```
struct _CopyItfFromAdaptItf {
    static HRESULT copy(T** p1, CAdapt< CComPtr<T> >* p2) {
    if( *p1 = p2->m_T ) return (*p1)->AddRef(), S_OK;
    return E_POINTER;
}


IZipFileEntry : public IDispatch
{
    public:
        virtual /* [helpstring][id][propget] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_name( 
        /* [retval][out] */ BSTR *pVal) = 0;

        virtual /* [helpstring][id][propget] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_lastModified( 
        /* [retval][out] */ DATE *pVal) = 0;

        virtual /* [helpstring][id][propget] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_fileSize( 
        /* [retval][out] */ long *pVal) = 0;

        virtual /* [helpstring][id][propget] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE get_compressedSize( 
        /* [retval][out] */ long *pVal) = 0;

    };


typedef ICollectionOnSTLImpl<IZipFileDir1, EntryList, IZipFileEntry*, _CopyItfFromAdaptItf<IZipFileEntry>, EntryEnum> EntryCollection;
```

Definition of ICollectionOnSTLImpl

```
class ICollectionOnSTLImpl : 
    public T
{
public:
        STDMETHOD(get_Count)(_Out_ long* pcount)
        {
        if (pcount == NULL)
            return E_POINTER;
        ATLASSUME(m_coll.size()<=LONG_MAX);

        *pcount = (long)m_coll.size();

        return S_OK;
    }
    STDMETHOD(get_Item)(
        _In_ long Index, 
        _Out_ ItemType* pvar)
    {
        //Index is 1-based
        if (pvar == NULL)
            return E_POINTER;
        if (Index < 1)
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
        Index--;
        CollType::const_iterator iter = m_coll.begin();
        while (iter != m_coll.end() && Index > 0)
        {
            iter++;
            Index--;
        }
        if (iter != m_coll.end())
            hr = CopyItem::copy(pvar, &*iter);
        return hr;
    }
    STDMETHOD(get__NewEnum)(_Outptr_ IUnknown** ppUnk)
    {
        if (ppUnk == NULL)
            return E_POINTER;
        *ppUnk = NULL;
        HRESULT hRes = S_OK;
        CComObject<EnumType>* p;
        hRes = CComObject<EnumType>::CreateInstance(&p);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
        {
            hRes = p->Init(this, m_coll);
            if (hRes == S_OK)
                hRes = p->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IUnknown), (void**)ppUnk);
        }
        if (hRes != S_OK)
            delete p;
        return hRes;
    }
    CollType m_coll;
};
```

Comment: Yes, its because its an SDK file and you are absolutely not supposed to change them. You are obviously supplying a pointer to a const variable to a function that wants to change said variable. Look through the template error until you find your line of code that causes the problem. Template errors being the worst to decrypt explains why ATL is so annoying ;)

Comment: It says the line of code is trying to write to a spot that you should not be writing to.   It may be right.

Comment: Actually I got an error message stating "atlimpl.cpp" is not found/could not be opened. As per the recommendation in the below link, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4117ea1a-23a9-4b57-a753-547f9fc1087b/statregcpp-atlimplcpp-is-obsolete?forum=vcgeneral , I commented the #include<atlimpl.cpp> line, then on build I get this error. Is it incorrect to have commeted #include<atlimpl.cpp> ?

Comment: Also, Please not that "atlimpl.cpp" which is part of sdk file in VS 2008, is no longer present in vs 2013

Comment: How exactly is `ICollectionOnSTLImpl` class used in your code?

Comment: @sharptooth I've added few more code samples for your reference.

Comment: You wrote `const_iterator iter` but you are passing it to a function that wants a non-const pointer.

Comment: @RaymondChen: `ICollectionOnSTLImpl` is in atlcom.h so he'd better not change it.

Comment: The you need to fix `_CopyItfFromAdaptItf`. If there is a conflict between A and B, and you can't change A, then you need to fix B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without all the code but it looks like I've reproduced the problem with the following code:

```
template<class T>
struct _CopyItfFromAdaptItf {
    static HRESULT copy(T** p1, CAdapt< CComPtr<T> >* p2) {
        if( *p1 = p2->m_T ) return (*p1)->AddRef(), S_OK;
        return E_POINTER;
    }
};

IDispatch** disp;
const CAdapt<CComPtr<IDispatch>> adapt; // note const here
_CopyItfFromAdaptItf<IDispatch>::copy( disp, &adapt ); //error C2664 here
```

The compiler output is

```
File(Line) : error C2664: '_CopyItfFromAdaptItf<T>::copy' :
  cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const ATL::CAdapt<T> *' to 'ATL::CAdapt<T> *'
    with
    [
      T=IDispatch
    ]
    and
    [
      T=ATL::CComPtr<IDispatch>
    ]
    and
    [
      T=ATL::CComPtr<IDispatch>
    ]
    Conversion loses qualifiers
```

which pretty much matches the output you cited.

The problem is that `_CopyItfFromAdaptItf::copy()` wants a pointer to non-const but a pointer to const is passed. Code that passes a pointer to const is inside atlcom.h which belongs to SDK headers and so you'd better not change it.

Also if `_CopyItfFromAdaptItf::copy()` signature is changed to accept a pointer to const:

```
static HRESULT copy(T** p1, const CAdapt< CComPtr<T> >* p2) // note addition of const
```

it still compiles just fine. `_CopyItfFromAdaptItf` is nowhere in the ATL headers so I guess it's in your code and you can change it.

So it looks like the solution is to simple change `_CopyItfFromAdaptItf::copy()` to accept a pointer to const and the problem will go away.